# Traefik: How do I redirect https to http with Docker?

Tags: docker, http, redirect, https, traefik

I inherited a project that is using Traefik with Docker but I have no experience with Traefik so seeking some assistance.
Say I have domain https://xxx.testsite.com I have been asked to redirect any traffic from https to http.
I've tried configuring a middleware to redirect but it didn't work.

Currently, if I visit http://xxx.testsite.com my website does load.
If I visit https://xxx.testsite.com I get a 404 page not found.

How can I can configure my files to accomplish this?

My project directory structure is

```
my_project/
├─ testsite/
│  ├─ docker-compose.yml
│  ├─ docker-compose-https.yml
│  ├─ web
│  │  ├─index.html
├─ traefik.yml
├─ traefik.toml
├─ acme.json
```

`my_project/traefik.toml`

```
[web]
logLevel = "DEBUG"
defaultEntryPoints = ["https","http"]

[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"
  [entryPoints.dashboard]
    address = ":8088"
  [entryPoints.https]
  address = ":443"
  [entryPoints.https.tls]
[retry]

[docker]
endpoint = "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
domain = "jltxxxx.com"
watch = true
exposedByDefault = false
network = "jh"

[acme]
email = "xxxxxx@gmail.com"
storage = "acme.json"
entryPoint = "https"
onHostRule = true
[acme.httpChallenge]
entryPoint = "http"
```

`my_project/traefik.yml`

```
version: '2'

services:
  traefik:
        image: traefik:v1.7
    restart: unless-stopped
        networks:
          - testsite
    ports:
      - '8100:80'
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - ./traefik.toml:/traefik.toml
      - ./acme.json:/acme.json
    logging:
     options:
       max-size: 100m

networks:
  testsite:
    external:
      name: testsite_default
```

`my_project/testsite/docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '2'
services:
    web:
      image: 'flipbox/php:72-apache'
      restart: unless-stopped
      volumes:
          - '.:/var/www/html/'
      labels:
        - 'traefik.enable=true'
        - 'traefik.backend=testsite_web_1'
        - 'traefik.docker.network=testsite'
        - 'traefik.frontend.rule=Host:xxx.testsite.com, www.xxx.testsite.com'
      logging:
       options:
         max-size: 500m
```

`my_project/testsite/docker-compose-https.yml`

```
version: '2'
services:
    web:
      image: 'flipbox/php:72-apache'
      restart: unless-stopped
      volumes:
          - '.:/var/www/html/'
      labels:
        - 'traefik.enable=true'
        - 'traefik.port=80'
        - 'traefik.frontend.entryPoints=https'
        - 'traefik.backend=testsite_web_1'
        - 'traefik.docker.network=testsite'
        - 'traefik.frontend.rule=Host:xxx.testsite.com, www.xxx.testsite.com'    
      logging:
         options:
         max-size: 500m
```

Answer (score 0):

*I'm not familiar with the Traefik v1 syntax, but I hope this code for Traefik v2 might give an idea how to do this in v1. And also to answer the question for other people using Traefik v2.*

First of all, there are many things in this configuration that doesn't seem right. To name an example, the ports specified in the static config and the ports you expose in the Traefik container do not match.

But to come back to the redirect part, there are two options:

Either you can redirect ALL incoming traffic to HTTPS by adding the following to the **static** configuration of the Traefik container:

```yaml
command:
    - "--entrypoints.websecure.address=:443"
    - "--entrypoints.web.address=:80"
    - "--entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entryPoint.to=websecure"
    - "--entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entryPoint.scheme=https"
    - "--entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entrypoint.permanent=true"
```

Or you can redirect traffic to HTTPS for a single container by adding the following to the **dynamic** configuration of the application container:

```yaml
labels:
    - "traefik.enable=true"
    - "traefik.http.middlewares.myapp-redirect.redirectscheme.scheme=https"
    - "traefik.http.middlewares.myapp-redirect.redirectscheme.permanent=true"
    - "traefik.http.routers.myapp.middlewares=myapp-redirect"
    - "traefik.http.routers.myapp.rule=Host(`myapp.localhost`)"
    - "traefik.http.routers.myapp.entrypoints=web"
    - "traefik.http.routers.myapp-secure.rule=Host(`myapp.localhost`)"
    - "traefik.http.routers.myapp-secure.entrypoints=websecure"
    - "traefik.http.routers.myapp-secure.tls=true"
    - "traefik.http.routers.myapp-secure.tls.certresolver=le"
```